# What is the data type of an internet explorer window in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, types

I was just wondering how do we have to declare "ie" from the following code?

```
Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you looking for `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?

Comment: Try `ie` as `Object`, or `Variant` as default?

Comment: The data type is probably some `Window` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Object` but it's easier if you enable the [Microsoft Internet Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v%3Dvs.85)) library as it creates more specific objects. This allows you to use intellisense while coding which makes it much less of a guessing game of what properties and actions are available. Here's some sample code once you have it enabled.

```
Dim ieobject As InternetExplorer

Set ieobject = New InternetExplorer
ieobject.Visible = True


ieobject.navigate Url:="https://www.StackOverFlow.com"


'get the HTML document for the page.
    Dim ieDOCUMENT As HTMLDocument
    Set ieDOCUMENT = ieobject.document
```

[This site covers it well](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s324/vba-ie.htm) (along with a lot of other VBA topics)

If you get the error *User-defined Type not defined*, you haven't enabled the Microsoft Internet Controls library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place a breakpoint (F9) in your procedure, then bring up the *Locals* toolwindow (View /> Locals) when the breakpoint is hit.

The runtime data types will appear under the "Type" column<sup>1</sup>:

[image: VBE locals toolwindow]

If you are not referencing the type library where these classes and interfaces are defined, the type to use at the declaration site is `Object`, or `Variant` - because there is no compile-time reference to the library, the compiler cannot bind the types at compile-time, so you would get a compile error if you tried to declare the object variables otherwise.

[With a reference to the appropriate type library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707312/1188513), you can still use late binding and declare everything `As Object`, but that would be silly with the library right there waiting to be used.

In your particular example (as provided anyway), the type of `ie` is... `Object`, and the reference is `Nothing`, so expect any member call against `ie` to throw error 91:

[image]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Unless user interfaces are involved... that's a bug in the VBE, unlikely to ever see a fix.</sub>